# Use nested function as action for `UIButton`

Tags: swift, function, uibutton, selector, target

I'm trying to add a target to my UIButton, but get an error when trying to use a nested function as its action.

Here's my code:

```
func createAddView() {
    let addButton = UIButton()

    func remove(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Remove")
    }

    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

it is giving me this warning:

```
warning: No method declared with Objective-C selector 'remove'.
```

I need the ´remove´ function to be nested in the ´createAddView´function because I need to remove and fade out some other UIViews that is being create in the ´createAddView´ function

Anyone knows how I can do this?

Comment: You cannot use a nested function as target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802074/nested-function-selector-in-swift-for-testing

Comment: move your `func remove(sender: UIButton)` outside your `createAddView()` and try?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, cause `func remove` is exist only in `func createAddView` block.
There is no restriction to add one `#selector()` to multiple `UIControl`'s. So you can declare `func remove` in class block and add it as `#selector` every time you create a new button.

Answer (score 0):

Because the func remove is create within createAddView() method .

here´s the fixed code :

```
func createAddView() {
    let view = UIView() //added for testing purposes 
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320  , height: 640) //added for testing purposes
    let addButton = UIButton()
    addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50) //added for testing purposes


    view.addSubview(addButton)



    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remove(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}

func remove(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in
        print("Add")
    }) {(Bool) -> Void in
        print("Done")
    }
}
```